# After system lock and unlock , the display for chrome and slack are not proper

Tags: 18.04, bios, lock-screen, slack

Am using ubuntu v18.04 , bios v1.5.1 and display manager "Light Display Manager".
After every lock and unlock of the dell laptop , few application UI are kind of messy. am unable to reuse those applications after system lock. attaching the screenshots for reference. How to resolve this?
**Note**: also facing this issues only in slack and chrome.

[image]